# Problem cropping an image to a perfect square with GD library

Tags: php, gd, gdlib

I use a class that automatically crops an image as a square based on some options. The problem is that when the image is of a certain width and height, the image is cropped but a 1px column of black pixels is added to the right of the image. I think that the problem is in  the mathematics used to generate the new image size... Maybe when the division of the height and the width gives a decimal number then the square is not perfect and the black pixels are added...

Any solution?

This is how I call the object:

```
$resizeObj = new resize($image_file); // *** 1) Initialise / load image
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(182, 182, 'crop'); // *** 2) Resize image
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($destination_path, 92); // *** 3) Save image
```

The part of the class I'm talking about:

```
private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {

        $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
        $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

        if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
            $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
        } else {
            $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
        }

        $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
        $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
        $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
        $cropStartY = 0; // start crop from top

        $crop = $this->imageResized;
        //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

        // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }
```

**Update:**

Maybe changing this:

```
$heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
$widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;
```

with this:

```
$heightRatio = round($this->height / $newHeight);
$widthRatio  = round($this->width /  $newWidth);
```

Comment: If it helps, I know for sure I copied one of the square-thumbnail generating examples in the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php to do this job, and it's working fine for me. Unfortunately I'm at work, and the code is from a personal project I don't have access to at the moment, so I can't tell you which it is -- but there's only a couple there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
```

looks suspicious.

If this is integer division then for images that are an odd number of pixels wide you'll get truncation. Try:

```
$cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2.0) - ( $newWidth / 2.0 );
```

Make sure that all your arithmetic is using real numbers, preferably double precision ones, but with numbers in the range you are dealing with it *should* be OK to work in single precision floats.

Comment: How to make sure that all the arithmetic is using real numbers??

Comment: @Jonathan - If this were C# or C++ I'd say declare them as `double`, but as PHP isn't strongly typed I'm not sure there's a "correct" way.

Comment: PHP does support typecasting http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting